# Selecting rows based on the value of columns in other rows

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, subquery, where-clause

For this problem I would be happy with a solution either in R (ideally with dplyr but other methods would also be OK) or pure SQL.

I have data consisting for individuals (`ID`) and email addresses, and a binary indicator representing whether the email address is the individual's primary email address (1) or not (0)

- all `ID`s have one and only one primary email address
- `ID`s can have several non-primary email addresses (or none)
- `ID`s can have the same email address as both primary and non-primary

For example:

```
   ID Email Primary
1   1     A       1
2   1     A       0
3   1     B       0
4   2     A       1
5   2     A       0
6   3     C       1
7   4     D       1
8   4     C       0
9   5     E       1
10  5     F       0
```

(The actual dataset has around half a million rows)

I wish to identify IDs where an email address is non-primary, but is primary for a different ID. That is, I want to select rows where:

- Primary is 0
- There exists another row where that ID is Primary but for a different ID

Thus in the data above, I want to select row 5 (because the email address is non-primary, but primary in row 1 for a different `ID` and row 8 (because it is non-primary, but primary in row 6 for a different `ID`) and row 2

For R users, here is the toy dataframe above:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), Email = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "D", "C", "E", "F"), Primary = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Why do you select row 5 and not row 2? Row 2 also has Primary as 0 and  There exists another row where that ID is Primary but for a different ID (row 4 for ID = 2).

Comment: @RonakShah sorry, you are quite right. I will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select rows where

- `Primary = 0`
- number of `ID`'s for that `Email` is greater than 1.
- There is atleast one `primary = 1` for that `Email`

Using `dplyr`, you can do this as :

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(Email) %>% 
   filter(Primary == 0, n_distinct(ID) > 1, any(Primary == 1))

#     ID Email Primary
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1 A           0
#2     2 A           0
#3     4 C           0
```

Since you have big data a `data.table` solution would be helpful :

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[Primary == 0 & uniqueN(ID) > 1 & any(Primary == 1)], Email]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It seemed to work. I have always used 3 backticks or 4 spaces.

Comment: No problem, I think new update killed R formatting... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401064/680068

Answer (score 3):

In *SQL*, you can use `exists` for this:

```sql
select t.*
  from mytable t
where t.primary = 0 
      and exists (
                  select 1 
                  from mytable t1 
                  where t1.email = t.email 
                    and t1.id <> t.id 
                    and t1.primary = 1
                  )
```